# Undoing the Workbook_BeforeClose event

Tags: excel, vba, events

I have written some code in the Workbook_BeforeClose event subroutine to suppress a custom menu bar (in Excel 2016) when the user closes the file. This works perfectly for my purposes when the user actually proceeds with closing their Excel file.

However, if the user makes unsaved changes and tries to close or exit, a system generated menu appears asking if they want to Save, Don't Save or Cancel. Cancel seems to cause problems as my Workbook_BeforeClose subroutine has already executed at this point.

If the end user then opts to choose "Cancel", then it would be ideal if the Workbook_BeforeClose event were to have been skipped, or alternatively some code gets run to reinstate the menu is this specific circumstance. Does anybody know what sort of event state occurs when an Excel user Cancels Closing their Excel File so that I can reload the menu when this happens?

Comment: Workbook_WindowDeactivate(ByVal Wn As Window) fires after the BeforeClose event and the Save prompt, but NOT if the user chose CANCEL

Comment: FWIW if the user cancels that prompt, the VBIDE has already unloaded its add-ins at that point, too - and there's no way around it. Maybe `Application.DisplayAlerts` can be set to `False` in the `BeforeClose` handler, to *prevent* the prompt from showing up?

Comment: You could ask that question in `Workbook_Close` event, Then just give them a `Yes` or `No` option. If they click on `Yes`, save the workbook before closing. If `No`, set save to false before closing

Comment: Thank you very much for the insightful answers. Tin, I think I have a reasonable stopgap using the Workbook_WindowDeactivate(ByVal Wn As Window) event. I added a module level Boolean Variable that gets set to True only during the Workbook_BeforeClose event and then moved my code to suppress the menus to the Workbook_WindowDeactivate(ByVal Wn As Window). The Boolean is set to false when the workbook opens or activates. It is not elegant, and will have to do a fair bit of testing, but does seem to address this specific problem.

Comment: Zac, I am a bit of a novice, but modifying the Workbook_Close event to simply yield a vbYesNo rather than a vbYesNoCancel seems much simpler than what I have done. However, I do not know how to access and modify the code for this message box as the Workbook_Close event does not appear in the dropdown in my VBA editor. Any further guidance on how I would go about implementing your suggestion would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I'm skeptical that Excel unloads addins if user cancels a close-action. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @johnywhy not Excel, the VBIDE that's hosted in it. And agreed, it doesn't make sense. Still how it works =)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon "the VBIDE that's hosted in it" - Unclear. You mean VB addins? And those are unloaded if a workbook close is canceled? Even if there are other books open?